# Animator state in not checking rather completed or not

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

In my game I want to check that one state in animator is completed then manually I trigger another state, But I am unable to check that. 
Any suggestions where I am going wrong, here is code I have done so for, this code is in update function (parameter 'for_fire' and state name 
'Standing fire 3' is same for one state):

```
counter_anim++;
if (counter_anim >= 5) 
{
    counter_anim = 0;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, new_target_points);
        if (distance <= 1.0f && !enter_state) 
        {
            navmesh.Stop ();
            anim.SetBool ("is_Firing", false);
            anim.SetBool ("for_fire", true);

            print ("i come here   "+this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("Standing fire 3"));

            if (this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("Standing fire 3") == true) 
            {
                enter_state = true;  // this bool variable is not getting true
            }
        }
}
//print (enter_state+"     "+ this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("Standing fire 3"));

if (enter_state && this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("Standing fire 3")==false) 
{
    //print (this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("Standing fire 3"));

    anim.SetBool ("for_fire",false);
    anim.SetBool ("new_pos",true);
    fire_occured ();
}
```

I am making like, enemy go to his position and stand their for while and fire, after that this animation stops and next animation starts.

Comment: There are several things I don't see here that can go wrong. E.G. distance to new_target_points, are you sure it gets lower than 1f? is enter_state starting as false?

Comment: Yes it gets lower than 1f, I did debugging here so I am sure, and enter_state is false by default

Comment: Eventhough I've seen some implementations with the IsName() method I usually go for tag if(this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("Standing fire 3")). This definitelly worked for me. In the Animator than tag your states with it.

Comment: OMG!!!! this works for me,, Thanks @Hrusilov, post this as a answer, I will vote up.(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copied from comment:**

Even though I've seen some implementations with the IsName() method I usually go for tag if(this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("Standing fire 3")). This definitely worked for me. In the Animator than tag your states with it.

My guess is that the name convention didn't work. Maybe you misspelled it or you were using the name of the clip not the state.